# Add page break in pdf generated using mpdf library

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm using php library mpdf for generating pdf files from HTML content. For short paragraph text mpdf is working normally but when there is more than one page long content mpdf is generating pdf file within a single page with very small font. It doesn't worked when I gave sufficient font-size.

Is there any parameter that can be set for page break in mpdf ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68139757/mpdf-page-break-based-on-element-height

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use `<div>` instead of using `<table>`. MPDF will shrink the content inside `<tr> <td>` to o